# c initialize an array of structs of structs

Tags: c, struct

I have 2 structs, path and paths.   Then, define an array of paths to hold my data:

```
enum MAX_NEIGHBOR {MAX_NEIGHBOR = 256};
enum MAX_NUM_PATHS {MAX_NUM_PATHS = 100};

typedef struct {
    int id;
    int path[MAX_NEIGHBOR];
} path;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    path pathsIKnow[MAX_NUM_PATHS];
} paths;

paths pathsIKnow[MAX_NEIGHBOR];
```

I am currently initializing the array in a big loop at runtime, which takes too much time.  Is there a way I can initialize this without a loop, such as during definition of the paths array?

Current loop code:

```
void initKnownPaths() {
    for(int j=0;j<MAX_NEIGHBOR;j++){
        paths pathsToI = pathsIKnow[j];
        pathsToI.id = 999;

        for(int i=0 ;i < MAX_NUM_PATHS;i ++){
            path pathToupdate = pathsToI.pathsIKnow[i];
            pathToupdate.id = 999;
            for(int j=0 ;j < MAX_NEIGHBOR;j++){
                int cPathValue = pathToupdate.path[j];

                cPathValue = 999;
                pathToupdate.path[j] = cPathValue;
            }

            pathsToI.pathsIKnow[i] = pathToupdate;
            pathsIKnow[j] = pathsToI;

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your init function is copying large amounts of data around, and is doing a lot of work that gets thrown away.  You should clean that up first.  Also, having two different variables named `j` is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling using GCC, then instead of `initKnownPaths` function you can replace the structure variable `pathsIKnow` of type `struct paths` by this:

```
paths pathsIKnow[MAX_NEIGHBOR] =
{
  [0 ... MAX_NEIGHBOR - 1] =
  {
    999,
    {
      [0 ... MAX_NUM_PATHS - 1] =
      {
    999,
    {
[0 ... MAX_NEIGHBOR - 1] = 999}}}}};
```

If you are not using GCC, then you should improve your existing function based on [@1201ProgramAlarm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231607/1201programalarm) suggestions

**Note:** If you use the first method, your compiled binary file size will increase, however this should reduce the run-time. (*time-space tradeoff !!*)

**References** :

- [GCC DOCS](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)
- [how-to-initialize-all-members-of-an-array-to-the-same-value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207702/10155936)